# Same code but not working Android (Cursor, update database)

Tags: android, cursor

I have a big problem.
This is 1st method `updateIncomeNoteChangeDay()`

```
res1.moveToFirst();
while (res1.isAfterLast() == false){
    if(res1.getString(1).equals(Date_OldNote) == true){
        moneyIncomeDaily = Integer.parseInt(res1.getString(3));
        moneyIncomeDaily = moneyIncomeDaily - Integer.parseInt(Money_OldNote);
        long updateTableDailyIncome = db.updateTableDailyIncomeStatistic(res1.getString(1), Integer.toString(moneyIncomeDaily), Integer.parseInt(idUser), Integer.parseInt(res1.getString(0)));
    }
    res1.moveToNext();
}

res1.moveToFirst();
while (res1.isAfterLast() == false){
    if (res1.getString(1).equals(Date_Note)==true){
        moneyIncomeDaily = Integer.parseInt(res1.getString(3));
        moneyIncomeDaily = moneyIncomeDaily + Integer.parseInt(Money_Note);
        long updateTableDailyIncome = db.updateTableDailyIncomeStatistic(res1.getString(1), Integer.toString(moneyIncomeDaily), Integer.parseInt(idUser), Integer.parseInt(res1.getString(0)));
        tempIncomeDailyNewNote = tempIncomeDailyNewNote + 1;
    }
    res1.moveToNext();
}

res1.close();
```

This is 2nd method `updatePayNoteChangeDay()`

```
res2.moveToFirst();
while (res2.isAfterLast() == false){
    if(res2.getString(1).equals(Date_OldNote) == true){
        moneyPayDaily = Integer.parseInt(res2.getString(3));
        moneyPayDaily = moneyPayDaily - Integer.parseInt(Money_OldNote);
        long updateTableDailyPay = db.updateTableDailyPayStatistic(res2.getString(1), Integer.toString(moneyPayDaily), Integer.parseInt(idUser), Integer.parseInt(res2.getString(0)));
    }
    res2.moveToNext();
}

res2.moveToFirst();
while (res2.isAfterLast() == false){
    if (res2.getString(1).equals(Date_Note)==true){
        moneyPayDaily = Integer.parseInt(res2.getString(3));
        moneyPayDaily = moneyPayDaily + Integer.parseInt(Money_Note);
        long updateTableDailyPay = db.updateTableDailyPayStatistic(res2.getString(1), Integer.toString(moneyPayDaily), Integer.parseInt(idUser), Integer.parseInt(res2.getString(0)));
        tempPayDailyNewNote = tempPayDailyNewNote + 1;
    }
    res2.moveToNext();
}

res2.close();
```

And here is my if - else

```
if (Type_Note.equals(Type_OldNote)==true&&Type_Note.equals("Thu")&&Date_Note.equals(Date_OldNote) == true){
    updateIncomeNoteJustChangeMoney(Date_Note, Money_Note, idUser, idNote, Date_OldNote, Money_OldNote);
}else if (Type_Note.equals(Type_OldNote)==true&&Type_Note.equals("Thu")&&Date_Note.equals(Date_OldNote) == false){
    updateIncomeNoteChangeDay(Date_Note, Money_Note, idUser, idNote, Date_OldNote, Money_OldNote);
}else if (Type_Note.equals(Type_OldNote)==true&&Type_Note.equals("Chi")&&Date_Note.equals(Date_OldNote) == true){
    updatePayNoteJustChangeMoney(Date_Note, Money_Note, idUser, idNote, Date_OldNote, Money_OldNote);
}else if (Type_Note.equals(Type_OldNote)==true&&Type_Note.equals("Chi")&&Date_Note.equals(Date_OldNote) == false){
    updatePayNoteChangeDay(Date_Note, Money_Note, idUser, idNote, Date_OldNote, Money_OldNote);
}
```

Here is list Cursor

```
Cursor res1 = db.getDataTableDailyIncomeStatistic(Integer.parseInt(idUser));
Cursor res2 = db.getDataTableDailyPayStatistic(Integer.parseInt(idUser));
```

I checked it many times. They are like each other. But i dont understand why this method `updateIncomeNoteChangeDay()` work perfect. But method `updatePayNoteChangeDay()` is nerver working.

Comment: please tell us what is wrong ;) "it does not work" is too broad :)

Comment: 2nd method updatePayNoteChangeDay() does not work. I dont know what is wrong. See my if - else. It just different **Type_Note.equals("Thu")** and **Type_Note.equals("Chi")**. But **Type_Note.equals("Thu")** work and **Type_Note.equals("Chi")** does not work

Comment: still not understandable... nobody can guess how it should work and what is actually wrong. "Don't know what is wrong" ... If you don't even know what you really want, we can't help you ;)

Comment: **long updateTableDailyPay = db.updateTableDailyPayStatistic(res2.getString(1), Integer.toString(moneyPayDaily), Integer.parseInt(idUser), Integer.parseInt(res2.getString(0)));** does not work

Comment: It's unbelievable how you do not want to understand that "does not work" MEANS NOTHING TO US. If you get no error, and that you can't tell us what are the expected and the received results, we can't help you. I give up here, sorry guy ;)

Comment: **moneyPayDaily ** was updated. But i cant update table. I used this command in other method. It can work :(

Comment: I'm sorry because i'm not good at English. So i want to say many things, but i cant express to you. I'm so so sorry about it

Answer (score 1):

Does it crash ? What is not working ?
If you need the same database for to actions you are doing it wrong.
From what I can see updateIncomeNoteChangeDay and updatePayNoteChangeDay, both have some structure, the easy way is to make an instance of the DB and than make two separate methods.

Comment: method "  updatePayNoteChangeDay" Is not working. It doesn't crash. 
I want update Money in res1 when i change Date, and i want update Money in res2 when i change Date. When i change Date in my app with TypeNote = "Thu", method "updateIncomeNoteChangeDay " work perfect, But when i change Date in my app with TypeNote = "Chi". Nothing is updated. :(